# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

Tags: multithreading, listview, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I want to show detected beacon UUID, Major and Minor in the list view. When my onServiceConnect() method is called, it will add items(UUID, Major, Minor values) in the list. Although it shows the list items when i debug my code but my app terminates after a few seconds leaving me with this error:

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your
>   adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

Here's my code

```
public class NotifyDemo_Sc4 extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    Button buttonNotify,b2;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private int nos_calls=0;
    private boolean run_call=true;
    Beacon beacon;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifydemo);
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView3);
        buttonNotify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewNotific);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondemo);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(NotifyDemo_Sc4.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/name.html");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // requestLayout();
        beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);

        beaconManager.setDebug(true);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
        beaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(false);

        Log.d(TAG, "didEnterRegion" + beaconManager);
        mBluetoothAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();

        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
      //  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, arrayOfDevices);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        blefunction();
        // nos_calls++;
        final Region region = new Region("myBeaons", Identifier.parse("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"), null, null);
        // runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {

                    @Override
                    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                            beacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                            String b = beacon.toString();
                            double b2 = beacon.getDistance();
                            Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about " + beacon.toString() + " Distance " + beacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
                            Log.i(TAG, "Beacon Detected" + beacon.toString());
                            arrayList.add("Beacon UUID, Major, Minor:" + b + "\n");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " The beacon " + "The distance " + beacon.getDistance() + " meters away.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }}, 3000);

            try
            {
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", Identifier.parse("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"), Identifier.parse("0"), Identifier.parse("1")));
            }
            catch(RemoteException e){}
    }
    void blefunction()
    {if(run_call = true){
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Scanned BLE device with mac: " + device.getAddress());
                String add = "C4:BE84:05:EE:BF";
                long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i(TAG, "in " + (e) + "ms");
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BLE Scanned Device Address: " + device.getAddress() + "/n" + "Time in milliseconds:" + e + " ms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                run_call = false;  }
        });}}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by manipulating the `adapter` or the `arrayList` it contains from any thread that is not the UI thread.  There is at least one line that changes the `arrayList` in a beacon callback, which is not on the UI thread:

```
arrayList.add("Beacon UUID, Major, Minor:" + b + "\n");
```

To fix the problem, you need to wrap that line in a block like below.  For best efficiency, you should wrap the whole beacon iteration loop in a block like this, so you aren't creating a new `Runnable` repeatedly inside the loop.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       ...
    }
});
```

You also need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from the UI thread to have the changes take effect.  You should add that to the end of the block.

While this is not part of the question, it is worth noting that the following line inside the loop that iterates over the `beacons` will set the value of `beacon` to the first item in the list.  This likely defeats the purpose of iterating over `beacons`, so you may want to remove that line:

```
beacon = beacons.iterator().next();
```

Comment: I implemented the method runOnUiThread() but it didn't work out for me.I'm still getting the same error